# Azure Entity Framework AutomaticMigrationsEnabled changing datatype does not update database type

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to understand migrations. I have AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true; and created an initial migration.

If I add a new DBSet to the DBContext and publish this service then the database is updated with a corresponding new table as a suspected.

However, if I change the data type for a property in an entity class, for example change StatusID from int to string in the example below and publish the service the corresponding column data type does not get updated in the database.

If AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true, then why does the database not get automatically updated in this scenario?

Thanks

```
namespace myService.DataObjects
{
  public class Status : EntityData
  {
    public int StatusID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
  }
}

public class myServiceContext : DbContext
{....
public Configuration()
{
  AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
  AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
  SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new EntityTableSqlGenerator());
}
```

Comment: Do you experience this issue for every property, or just for StatusID?
Changing a column type like this usually involves dropping and recreating the column. StatusID is your PK, but in Azure SQL (I'm guessing based on the tags that you use Azure SQL) no table can exist without a PK. Not even while the PK is undergoing the change operation. 
Do you see any errors in your logs maybe?

Comment: StatusID is not the primary key, since I am inheriting from the EntityData class the primary key is ID from the EntityData class. I will try changing other properties but I feel like it is in an unstable state now and I need to reset the migration to really test it, but I am guessing that it is happening to all properties. I have been having issues keeping them in sync, one minute it seems to work then an issue like this pops up.

Comment: well it is working now for me, I am not sure if I was seeing things in the past or what, but I am going to mark this as answered. Thanks for any time spent on this

Answer (score 0):

It is working now for me, I am not sure if I was seeing things in the past or what, but I am going to mark this as answered. Thanks for any time spent on this